# I am getting errors while running npm install in my react project which I download from my git repo

Tags: reactjs

The error is -

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: cab_management_ui@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/icons
npm ERR!     @material-ui/icons@"^4.11.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Also, while doing so, it is not creating the `node_modules/` directory.
I am not able to understand the issue here and idk how to fix this. If anyone know how to, pls help.

Comment: Sounds like the MUI (Material UI) library is older than the React version.

Comment: Then what should I do?

Comment: Ideally, update to a version of MUI compatible with your version of React. MUI core is currently up to version v5.14.5

Comment: Or you can downgrade the react library to v17.x. MUI had a lot of changes since in v5.

Comment: and how to update it in vs code? any terminal code for that?

Comment: To downgrade react: ```npm i react@17 react-dom@17```

Answer (score 1):

How are you?
This is because, @material-ui doesn't support React 18,
which is you are now using.

So you can either downgrade React to v17.

Or you can install other version of Material UI.

You can check this issue.

https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32074

Answer (score 0):

Common error you are using latest version or react 18.2 but in this project mui is using react ^16.8.0 or ^17.0.0 that's why you are getting peer dependency conflict.

Comment: ok but how do I resolve this?

Comment: just use 17.0.0 in package.json and run npm install

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).